# How to create an automated reply in node-red if an incoming message?

Tags: node.js, node-red

How would it be possible to create an automatic reply if an message comes in from node 020110 that might be injected into the network again, in that sense I would like to send a packet to the depicted block Server in the schema below,where red line is the one I have to do yet.

[image]

As it can be seen, I get a feed from a sensor and I would like to send a message back to the network each time something comes to the node 02010110 using trigger function. However, I have faced with an issue, if I connect directly that two nodes( red line), I can see how the browser gets extremely slow and checking the debug terminal of node-red there are quite a lot of messages being sent to the trigger block, so I think that it certain point it cannot cope with them. The node only sends data each 5s.

So, I was wondering whether is some example, library or approach to do this in node red.

Answer (score 0):

With MQTT if a client is subscribed to the same topic it publishes on then it will have it's own messages delivered back to it.

So if you publish a message to the same topic for every incoming message your just going to continue to go round the loop processing the response as a new message and sending a new response.

If you want to send a "reply" (note, there is no direct concept of 1 to 1 messaging in MQTT, it is generally considered 1 to many) message you should send it to a different topic. The incoming message will already have the topic field set from the MQTT subscribe node, you can change this in the function node before sending it on to the MQTT publish node.

One approach may be to include a switch node before after the MQTT Subscribe node to filter out the reply messages if they can be easily identified.

Comment: I understand what you mention hardlib, I was wondering more if the trigger block in node-red is the one designed with that goal, because I want to send a new message/payload and no the incoming one from the node. I have seen that trigger block only allows string but not define your own payload.

Comment: The trigger node will actually make things worse as it sends 2 messages with a given delay between them for every message it receives . They will both have the same topic as the original message so if you wire this to a MQTT publish node you will get 2 messages back in on the subscriber node and that will cause 4 messages to be published and so on getting more each time unless one of the messages triggers a reset.

Comment: then how can I send a reply back if something is coming from that topic?

Comment: Use a different topic for replies if you need to respond

Comment: I cannot do that, I have to use the same topic with a different command

Comment: Then you need to parse the incoming message just after the subscriber node in Node-RED to identify responses and discard them

Comment: sorry I really don't understand what you mean

Comment: I would like to have a way to detect that a message has reached to the 020110 node, then I will trigger a message back to the topic